# How to fit the data?

Tags: fitting

Here is my attempt.

```
data = {{0., 2.61}, {0.1, 2.62}, {0.2, 2.62}, {0.3, 2.62}, {0.4, 
2.63}, {0.5, 2.63}, {0.6, 2.74}, {0.7, 2.98}, {0.8, 3.66}, {0.9, 
5.04}, {1., 7.52}, {1.1, 10.74}, {1.2, 12.62}, {1.3, 10.17}, {1.4,
 5}, {1.5, 2.64}, {1.6, 11.5}, {1.65, 35.4}};
NonlinearModelFit[data,a*Cosh[b*x^c*Sin[d*x^e]], {{a, 3}, {b, 0.2}, {c, 1}, {d, 1}, 
{e, 3}}, x, Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"]
```

> NonlinearModelFit::nrjnum: The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {a,b,c,d,e} = {3.,0.2,1.,1.,3.}.

The same issues appear with other initial points. As far as I know it, a good fit with the residuals of  quantity $0.01$ exists and can be found with Mathcad (not MATLAB).

Comment: The Jacobian contains `Log[x]` and your data contains `x == 0`

Comment: @Coolwater: There are other methods of fitting.

Comment: It's all about providing good starting values when there are 7 parameters (a, b, c, d, e, and the error variance) to estimate with only 18 (or 17 legitimate) limited precision data points.  Following @Coolwater 's approach gets you good starting values for use in `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: @JimB: I tried you advice, obtaining "NonlinearModelFit::nrjnum: The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {a,b,c,d,e} = {2.75699,1.66039,2.92883,4.74005,0.70619}.".

Comment: Drop the observation with x=0 and it will work just fine.

Comment: @JimB:   Did you test your advice?

Comment: Alternatively deal with the x=0 by writing a function `w[x_, exponent_] := If[x == 0, 0, x^exponent]` and fitting `a*Cosh[b*w[x, c]*Sin[d*w[x, e]]]`.

Comment: @JimB: The result $[a=2.756988300665134,b=1.660392236209295,c=2.9288462026903486,d=4.740066829408578,e=0.7061815020123664] $ is still far away from the optimal one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88917/discussion-between-jimb-and-user64494).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can minimize the cost function by using `NMinimize`

```
  ClearAll["Global`*"]

data = {{0., 2.61}, {0.1, 2.62}, {0.2, 2.62}, {0.3, 2.62}, {0.4, 
2.63}, {0.5, 2.63}, {0.6, 2.74}, {0.7, 2.98}, {0.8, 3.66}, {0.9, 
5.04}, {1., 7.52}, {1.1, 10.74}, {1.2, 12.62}, {1.3, 10.17}, {1.4,
 5}, {1.5, 2.64}, {1.6, 11.5}, {1.65, 35.4}};

        model[x_] := a Cosh[b x^c Sin[d x^e]]
        cost = Total[(#2 - model[#1])^2 & @@@ data];
        fit = NMinimize[{cost, 1 < a < 3, 1 < b < 3, 1 < c < 3, 1 < d < 3, 1 < e < 3},
     {a, b, c, d, e}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> {0.00112965, {a -> 2.61748, b -> 1.71949, c -> 2.30924, d -> 1.50333,
>   e -> 1.84597}}

```
Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} = {a, b, c, d, e} /. Last@fit];

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[model[k], {k, 0, 1.7}]]
```

[image]

You can also use `NonlinearModelFit` with appropriate constrain on parameters and method choice.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

data = {{0., 2.61}, {0.1, 2.62}, {0.2, 2.62}, {0.3, 2.62}, {0.4, 
2.63}, {0.5, 2.63}, {0.6, 2.74}, {0.7, 2.98}, {0.8, 3.66}, {0.9, 
5.04}, {1., 7.52}, {1.1, 10.74}, {1.2, 12.62}, {1.3, 10.17}, {1.4,
 5}, {1.5, 2.64}, {1.6, 11.5}, {1.65, 35.4}};

model[x_] := a Cosh[b x^c Sin[d x^e]]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, {model[x], 1 < a < 3, 1 < b < 3, 1 < c < 3, 1 < d < 3, 
   1 < e < 3}, {a, b, c, d, e}, x, 
  Method -> {"NMinimize", {Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}}, MaxIterations -> 1000]

nlm // Normal
```

> 2.61749 Cosh[1.71949 x^2.30926 Sin[1.50334 x^1.84596]]

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {a -> 2.61749, b -> 1.71949, c -> 2.30926, d -> 1.50334, e -> 1.84596}
>
> Same picture

Comment: Why was my  comment " ClearAll kills the data so the data should be inputted after ClearAll" deleted by an unknown to me person? This is unfair.

Comment: Maybe somebody deleted because   I modified the code and now it included the data in the code after ClearAll.

Answer (score 8):

Below `err` is defined as the residual sum of squares. Using `?NumericQ` on one of the arguments prevents `FindMinimum` from exact differentiation. In that way no problem arises even though the point with `x == 0` is included.

```
err[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_?NumericQ] = Total[(a*Cosh[b*#^c*Sin[d*#^e]] - #2)^2 & @@@ data];

res[x_] = a*Cosh[b*x^c*Sin[d*x^e]] /. Last[FindMinimum[err[a, b, c, d, e], {
                            {a, 3, 1/100, 25}, {b, 2, 1/100, 25}, {c, 1, 1/100, 25},
                            {d, 23/10, 1/100, 25}, {e, 2, 1/100, 25}}, Method -> "InteriorPoint"]]

Show[Plot[res[x], {x, 0, 1.65}, PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[data]]
```

[image]

Alternative start values result in a smaller sum of squares:

```
FindMinimum[err[a, b, c, d, e],
  {{a, 2.6174, 1/100, 25}, {b, 1.7195, 1/100, 25}, {c, 2.3092, 1/100, 25},
   {d, 1.5033, 1/100, 25}, {e, 1.845, 1/100, 25}}, Method -> "InteriorPoint"]
```

> {0.0011296543, {a -> 2.6174825, b -> 1.7194932, c -> 2.3092448, d -> 1.5033314, e -> 1.845972}}

These are highly likely optimal: When `x == 0` the regression formula equals just `a` and because of the first data point `a` should presumably be close to `2.61`.

If the last factor and `Cosh` are cancelled from the data values (using the right branch of ArcCosh) we get something we 2 peaks at high x-values:

```
data2 = Thread[{data[[All, 1]], PadLeft[{-1, -1}, 18, 1] ArcCosh[data[[All, 2]]/2.61]}]
ListPlot[data2]
```

[image]

We can solve for `b` and `c` such that the peaks are interpolated leaving only `d` and `e` for estimation:

```
sol = First[Solve[b #1^c Sin[d #1^e] == #2 & @@@ data2[[{-1, -6}]], {b, c}] /. C[1] -> 0 // Chop]
```

For different values of `d` and `e` let's look at the residual sum of squares excluding `x == 0`, because `sol` can't be evaluated in that instance

```
err0[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_?NumericQ] = Total[(a*Cosh[b*#^c*Sin[d*#^e]] - #2)^2 & @@@ Rest[data]];
search = Table[{d, e, Log[If[Im[#] == Im[#2] == 0, 
            Quiet[Min[err0[2.61, #, #2, d, e], 10^5.]], 10^5.]]} & @@
              ({b, c} /. sol), {d, 1/50, 7, 1/50}, {e, 1/50, 7, 1/50}] // Catenate;
ListPointPlot3D[search, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

the 2 smallest local minima of which coincide with the previous fits.

Comment: Thank you. Likely a somewhat better fit than your $2.75699 \cosh \left(1.66039 x^{2.92883} \sin \left(4.74005 x^{0.70619}\right)\right) $ is $[a= 2.61748239217892,b= 1.71949328471199,c= 2.30924398627606,d=
 1.50333104215966,e= 1.84597270613482]$. Can you kindly compare the results?

Comment: Colleagues, let us call  things by their proper names. The answer of @Coolwater is not bad, but  is not optimal.

Comment: That's interesting, but for $[a= 2.61748239217892,b= 1.71949328471199,c= 2.30924398627606,d=  1.50333104215966,e= 1.84597270613482]$ the sum of squared residuals equals $0.0000627585700895793 $. Hope you feel the difference.

Comment: You can see it at https://www.dropbox.com/s/o08c8x0cm0dutcl/deep%20fit.pdf?dl=0 .

Comment: From where "Alternative start values {a,}, {b, 1.7195,}, {c, 2.3092,},
   {d, 1.5033}, {e, 1.845}" which lead to  {a -> 2.6174825, b -> 1.7194932, c -> 2.3092448, d -> 1.5033314, e -> 1.845972}} are taken?

Comment: @user64494 They are the output from maple

Comment: Hope  you are sure now that  Maple produces an optimal solution, you don't.

Answer (score 3):

Just an extended comment that for this particular data/model combination it is difficult to find the values of parameters that minimize the residual sum of squares.  I think there are two main issues:

1. The surface is extremely bumpy which can get any iterative search algorithms to get lost.  (This is not necessarily a *Mathematic*, *Maple*, *R*, *SAS*, or *MathCAD" issue.)
2. Some of the parameter estimators are highly correlated with each other.  That also causes problems for finding the optimal parameter values.

Below is a contour plot of the sum of squares evaluated at @user64494 's optimal values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the neighborhoods of $d$ and $e$.  One can see the extreme bumpiness and the highly correlated nature of the estimators of $d$ and $e$.  The red dot indicates the location of the optimal values of $d$ and $e$.

[image: Bumpy surface near optimal values of d and e]

Comment: +1. Thank you for your valuable info. I think the increase of the data size to 30 changes nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

NonlinearModelFit works without  additional assumptions(Thanks @JimB 's comment) with `Method->"NMinimize"`

```
mod = NonlinearModelFit[Rest[data],a*Cosh[b*x^c*Sin[d*x^e]], { a , b , c, d,  e }, x,Method -> "NMinimize" ]
Show[{ListPlot[data], Plot[Normal[mod], {x, 0, 1.65}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: 1. You changed the data by Rest. 2. Your fit $ 2.76855 \cosh \left(1.65609 x^{2.93246} \sin \left(4.74049 x^{0.705923}\right)\right)$ is far away from optimal ones (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/o08c8x0cm0dutcl/deep%20fit.pdf?dl=0 ).

Comment: Yes I omitted the first data point(as @JimB recommended). My plot seems to fit the data quite well , not more.

Comment: One of the aims of my question is to pay attention of  Mathematica developers to the fact that NonlinearModelFit faces problems with some model functions.