# Fitting a function, a (x - 1)^b, to a given set of data

Tags: plotting, fitting

I have some data:

```
data = {{0.3, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.84, 0}, {1, 0}, {1.16, 159.1940}, {1.3, 
218.835}, {1.5, 278.0620}, {1.8, 340.758}, {2.01, 374.9820}, {2.3, 
416.09}}
```

which looks like:

[image]

It seems that some function of the form: $$a (x - 1)^b$$ should fit the data.

However, if we use

```
FindFit[data, a (x - 1)^b, {a, b}, x]
```

Mathematica gives: "The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {a,b} = {1.,1.}".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fit the data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190407/how-to-fit-the-data)

Comment: While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks for your comment. I'm new to this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just edited away your original data, but I used the original before you did.

Try this

```
data = {{0.3, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.84, 0}, {1, 0}, {1.16, 159.1940}, {1.3, 218.835}, 
  {1.5, 278.0620}, {1.8, 340.758}, {2.01, 374.9820}, {2.3, 416.09}, {2.49, 439.6510},
  {2.8, 473.367}, {2.99, 492.4980}, {3.3, 521.149}, {3.5, 538.4470}, {3.8, 563.011},
  {4.01, 579.4590}, {4.3, 600.841}, {4.51, 615.5270}, {4.8, 635.659}, {4.98, 647.8910},
  {5.3,668.192}, {5.5, 680.684}, {5.8, 698.925}, {6, 710.746}, {6.3, 728.073},
  {6.5, 739.405}, {6.8, 755.988}, {7, 766.847}, {7.3, 782.793}, {7.5, 793.227},
  {7.8, 808.629}, {8, 818.706}, {8.3, 833.612}, {8.5, 843.363}, {8.8, 857.815}, 
  {9, 867.267}, {9.3, 881.302}, {9.5, 890.536}, {9.8, 904.183}, {10, 913.159}};
sumsquared=Total[Map[(#[[2]]-a*(#[[1]]-1)^b)^2&,Drop[data,4]]];
sol=NMinimize[sumsquared,{a,b}];
Show[ListPlot[data],Plot[a(x-1)^b/.sol[[2]],{x,1,10}]]
```

You might notice that I dropped your first four data points because the zero values for y were causing complaints about complex values. Then I took the rest and did a sum of squares and minimized that. The result looks pretty good, even though the residual isn't close to zero, probably because of the size of your y values.

See if that is good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Many thanks! How can I get the value of a and b?

Comment: Look at the value of sol and you should see `{525.9802649238213, {a -> 368.267337527918, b -> 0.4111500193417123}}` and there are your `a` and `b` values.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help!

Comment: You be careful with that. Don't trust it. Don't trust me. Check all your assumptions. Test it before you depend on it. Glad it seemed to work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) model:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c]
fit = FindFit[data, Piecewise[{{a (x - 1)^b, x > 1}}], {a, b}, x]
```

> {a -> 373.218, b -> 0.446663}

```
Show[Plot[Piecewise[{{a (x - 1)^b, x > 1}}] /. fit, {x, 0, 3}], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image]

You can also try a three-parameter model:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c]
fit = FindFit[data, Piecewise[{{a (x - c)^b, x > c}}], {a, b, c}, x]
```

> {a -> 381.099, b -> 0.397244, c -> 1.04951}

```
Show[Plot[Piecewise[{{a (x - c)^b, x > c}}] /. fit, {x, 0, 3}], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Similar Q&A here:**

[Need to fit curve to 5 parameters: what's a problem with NonlinearModelFit?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163962/10397)

[How to fit the data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/190407/10397)

---

@kglr beated me to [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html), this one with [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)

```
data = {{0.3, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.84, 0}, {1, 0}, {1.16, 159.1940}, {1.3,
    218.835}, {1.5, 278.0620}, {1.8, 340.758}, {2.01, 374.9820}, {2.3,
    416.09}}

fit = NonlinearModelFit[
   data
   , Piecewise[{{a (x - 1)^b, x >= c}}, 0]
   , {a, b, {c, 1}}
   , x
   ];

Show[ 
 Plot[
  fit[x]
  , {x, 0, 3}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  , PlotRange -> {-100, 700}
  , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
  , Exclusions -> None
  ]
 , ListPlot[
  data
  , Joined -> False
  , PlotRange -> All
  , PlotStyle -> Black
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

```
fit["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]